# How to convert Tuple<object, object> to Tuple<string, DateTime>?

Tags: c#, tuples

I have a `List<object>` and in this list each object is a `Tuple<object, object>`. I would like to convert this list to `List<Tuple<string, DateTime>>` but the following doesnt work:

```
x = myList.First();
xx = (Tuple<DateTime, string>)x
```

Error: Unable to cast System.Tuple[obj, obj] to type System.Tuple[DateTime, String]

What can I do?

Comment: Is there a way you can remove the need for `List<object>` in the first place? If you already know what the type of each element is, don't advertise it as an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old style Tuple classes. C# 7.0 introduced the new (and sexy) ValueTuple types. See also: [Tuple types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples). C# supports them with a new syntax for tuple types, e.g. `(string, DateTime)`, and tuple values, e.g. `("hello", DateTime.Now)`.

There is no conversion defined between different types of value tuples. You can convert the whole list like this

```cs
var myList = new List<(object, object)> {
    ("hello", DateTime.Now),
    ("world", DateTime.Today)
};
List<(string, DateTime)> typedList = myList
    .Select(t => ((string)t.Item1, (DateTime)t.Item2))
    .ToList();
```

Or for a single item:

```cs
var x = myList.First();
var xx = ((string)x.Item1, (DateTime)x.Item2);
```

Or in a safe way and with [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching)

```cs
var x = myList.First();
if (x is (string s, DateTime d)) {
    var xx = (s, d);
}
```